# Having trouble getting TinyMCE to have an auto-sized width

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to incorporate TinyMCE into my CMS and I'm having the hardest time getting the width to resize to the size of my container. I'm using the advanced toolbar theme and the buttons do not drop below to form another row if the width is made smaller. I've searched a lot of forums and the TinyMCE docs and I can't find a solution that works for me.

So far I've tried:

- Setting the width in the tinyMCE.init
  function
- Setting auto_resize to true
- Changing the editor container width
  with CSS
- Changing the toolbars so they float
- Using the custom autoresize function
  in the wiki

It seems like a lot of people have had issues with this, and the forum moderator at TinyMCE isn't particularly helpful or polite. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Is the problem that your width is not small enough (due to the toolbar buttons), or that the width does not adjust at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a CSS rule for your TinyMCE theme/style file that works for me:

```
.sclSkin table.mceToolbar, .sclSkin tr.mceFirst .mceToolbar tr td, .sclSkin tr.mceLast .mceToolbar tr td { float: left; }
```

Make sure to replace the .sclSkin above with the name/identifier of your theme/skin;

Comment: This also worked for me. Many thanks.

TinyMCE still seems fairly ugly and jerky when you make this change, i.e. the buttons don't nicely and smoothly float over, it looks very jaggered etc. But it definitely works.

Comment: I added a `{height: 30px;}` and the icons wrapped better, mine were getting hung up on dropdowns and such.  Great solution, jason.